# What package conventions are there for ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, packaging

It's hard to describe this question. Let's look at an example:

The package `blender` depends i.e. on `blender-data`. I looked into both packages. `blender` contains only the application, a .desktop file and something like that, while `blender-data` also contains the application icons and so on. If I download blender from the original website, I get no package but a folder with everything I need.

Why is there a data package for blender? Are there more of those conventions? What kind of packages are there? Where can I read more about it? I found a lot of information about how to package and internal details, but nothing about naming conventions and the reason to create `*-data` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question here I'll use **LibreOffice** as an example (as nearly everyone has that installed).  If you're on Lubuntu (which doesn't have LibreOffice as standard office productivity suite) and you install LibreOffice, it's a *nearly empty package* although it has *package dependencies* for Writer, Calc, Base, etc.

A package dependency is just a "pointer" to another package.  Otherwise the servers at Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu) would quickly fill up with double, triple, quadruple, ... packages that all contain the same files!

A package that, in itself *only* contains such "pointers" is know as a *meta package*.

So the LibreOffice meta package pulls in its separate packages (E.g. `calc`), which pulls in their dependencies, which pull in theirs until all dependencies are resolved.
You *can* however install only Calc  *without* any of the other packages.

To see this in action, type the following command in a terminal:

```
apt-cache depends libreoffice-calc
```

And `blender` is just a very simple example of the above.

**Some more details:**

For some packages, things are broken into functional units: it is not uncommon to see packages called: application, application-data, application-plugins, application-dev, and some others which each contain respectively the application itself, a dataset or data to operate against, some plugins, or anything else...

**For the full details:**

Visit the package management [Development Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian).

Comment: And if that was too short for you, leave a comment @Fabby below.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Fabby's answer, there is one more point to consider: the architecture dependency of the package contents.

For example, the `blender` program itself will obviously depend on the architecture of the OS - you can only run `amd64` binaries on `amd64` OSes. However, a lot of data is not so dependent - the icon files, translations, programs written in languages like Python or Java, for example, can be the same for all architectures.

Thus, a first step in optimizing the package content is to split of such files in to common packages that are dependencies of the architecture specific version. The common files, typically in packages with `-data` have architecture `all`. The binary and library packages have architecture values of `amd64`, `i386`, `armhf`, etc.

This is actually one of [the Packaging Best Practices](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.html#bpp-archindepdata) recommended by Debian:

> It is not uncommon to have a large amount of architecture-independent data packaged with a program. For example, audio files, a collection of icons, wallpaper patterns, or other graphic files. If the size of this data is negligible compared to the size of the rest of the package, it's probably best to keep it all in a single package.
>
> However, if the size of the data is considerable, consider splitting it out into a separate, architecture-independent package (`_all.deb`). By doing this, you avoid needless duplication of the same data into eleven or more .debs, one per each architecture. While this adds some extra overhead into the `Packages` files, it saves a lot of disk space on Debian mirrors. Separating out architecture-independent data also reduces processing time of lintian (see [Section A.2, “Package lint tools”](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/tools.html#tools-lint)) when run over the entire Debian archive.

Such architecture-independent files often go into `/usr/share` - in fact, it is policy violation to have architecture-dependent files in that directory tree.

Then a way of organizing things naturally occur:

```
all
├── doc      # man pages, documentation in other formats
├── icons
├── themes
├── translations
└── etc.
arch
├── bin      # binaries
├── dbg      # binaries with debug symbols
├── lib      # shared library files
└── lib-dev  # header files and other shared library files for development
```

Comment: MGM: I bow to your wisdom and respectfully upvote!  ;-)